# Deleting an accepted answer with a negative score

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

A while back, I answered a question and it got accepted but I keep getting downvotes on it. People say the answer doesn't make sense (which could totally be right). I decided to delete the answer, but since it has been accepted, I can't. What can I do? I'm getting tired of getting downvotes for it.

And if I can't delete it, shouldn't this award me with some badge? :P Some `outlaw` badge for `accepted answer with a score of -5`.

Comment: You might as well link to the answer since we're all going to go find it anyway :) You could turn it into a community wiki (there's a checkbox if you go to the edit screen) or flag it with a custom flag explaining exactly the problem. It seems very unlucky that your answers apparently solved it for the OP but fails to solve it for apparently everyone else.

Comment: @ivarni - Enjoy :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924010/2083523

Comment: And it's gone now. Meta effect FTW

Comment: Too bad it was completely impossible to fix the answer :/ ...

Answer (score 15):

If you realize that your answer isn't helpful and that it is better off deleted  you should flag the post and explain to a moderator that you feel your own post isn't helpful and should be deleted, but that you can't delete it because it is accepted.  Moderators tend to honor such requests for deletion so long as it's clear that the author isn't vandalizing their own content, and that they sincerely feel that the answer isn't helpful, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Or, you can post it on Meta and let 3 20k users do it for you :P

Comment: @Machavity - Posted in a comment in the question :)